# Get result of INNER JOIN as array column, without duplicates

Tags: database, postgresql, inner-join

I have 2 simlpe tables, for example **product(id, name)** and **product_countries_rel(id, country_id, product_id)**. I.e. each product can have multiple countries.

Simple `INNER JOIN` query:

`SELECT p.id, p.name, pcr.country_id FROM product p INNER JOIN  product_countries_rel pcr ON p.id = pcr.product_id`.

will give this result:

```
 id    |      name    | country_id 
--------+-------------------------+-----------
     1 | ProductName1 | 23
     1 | ProductName1 | 25
     2 | ProductName2 | 56
     2 | ProductName2 | 57
```

But I want to get one record of `product` with `countries` column which will contain comma delimeted `country_ids`. I.e. I want this:

```
 id    |      name    | country_ids 
--------+-------------------------+-----------
     1 | ProductName1 | 23,25
     2 | ProductName2 | 56,57
```

How to achieve this? In case if it important - I'm using PostgreSQL 9.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Postgresql versions 9+ you can use `string_agg` to do this:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, string_agg(cast(pcr.country_id as varchar(5)), ',') 
FROM product p INNER JOIN product_countries_rel pcr ON p.id = pcr.product_id
GROUP BY p.id, p.name
```

In older versions the same result can be achieved using the `array_agg` function to build an array and making it a delimited string with the `array_to_string`:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, array_to_string(array_agg(pcr.country_id), ',') 
FROM product p INNER JOIN product_countries_rel pcr ON p.id = pcr.product_id
GROUP BY p.id, p.name
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, I was browsing the documentation and just realized and was about to append the answer. Thanks :)